# postfix + dovecot + mysql : virtual user management

Tags: mysql, postfix, dovecot

I have a postfix+dovecor email server configured to use mySql as virtual domains/users/aliases repository.

I know I can create/update/delete users in mySQL. The question is: Is there any simpler way to manage (create/update/delete) virtual users?

Comment: What can be easier than executing some easy sql statements? Please define a detailed questions and keep in mind that software recommendation are OT.

Comment: @deagh I am just asking, I am new to linux system administration and I wonder if someone automated the work before, but actually, I can do sql queries, that doesn't frighten me :) It bothers me a little remembering the syntax to encode the password hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `postfixadmin` and other web-based tools that intended exactly for email domains/users manipulations.